# Angular JS create multiple Dropdowns dynamically and Need validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I want to do validation for the dynamically create dropdown fields in angular js.
Here I pasred my JSON data and dynamically create dropdown fields and able to get even data but I want validation on default option "select a type".
.html file

```
  <div ng-repeat="CategoryList1 in Data">
  {{CategoryList1.fullImage}}
  <div ng-repeat="Attributes in CategoryList1.Attributes">
    <label class="item item-input">
      <span>  {{Attributes.name}}</span>
    </label>
    <select ng-model="atcStatusTasks" name="category-group" id="name" required
     ng-options="values.values for values in Attributes.Values" ng-change="atcStatusTasks===undefined ||GetValue(atcStatusTasks,Attributes.name)" >
       <option selected="selected" value="">select a type</option>
   </select>
   {{atcStatusTasks}}{{Attributes.name}}
  </div>
    <button class="button button-dark" ng-click="addToCart()"> Add To Cart</button>
    <span style="color:red">{{msg}}</span><br />
</div>
```

[image]

JSON data:

```
{
    "recordSetTotal": "1",
    "resourceId": "",
    "resourceName": "productview",
    "recordSetComplete": "true",
    "recordSetStartNumber": "0",
    "CatalogEntryView": [
        {
            "shortDescription": "Straight leg denim jeans",
            "buyable": "true",
            "longDescription": "A regular pair of jeans for your boy in dark blue, they are straight legged and have a distressed finish. Whisker washed for a faded effect, the comfortable fit makes him look tall and lean. A white shirt goes very well with these jeans.",
            "parentCategoryID": "10024",
            "metaKeyword": " Hermitage Collection",
            "resourceId": "",
            "Price": [
                {
                    "priceDescription": "I",
                    "priceUsage": "Offer",
                    "priceValue": "45.0"
                }
            ],
            "productType": "ProductBean",
            "name": "Hermitage Straight Leg Denim Jeans",
            "fullImage": "",
            "thumbnail": "",
            "uniqueID": "12390",
            "manufacturer": "Hermitage Collection",
            "numberOfSKUs": "4",
            "SKUs": [
            {
                "Attributes": [
                    {
                        "usage": "Defining",
                        "Values": [
                            {
                                "values": "Blue",
                                "identifier": "Blue",
                                "uniqueID": "7000000000000001341"
                            }
                        ],
                        "searchable": "false",
                        "identifier": "BoysPantsColor",
                        "comparable": "true",
                        "name": "Color",
                        "displayable": "true",
                        "uniqueID": "7000000000000000060"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "usage": "Defining",
                        "Values": [
                            {
                                "values": "S",
                                "identifier": "S",
                                "uniqueID": "7000000000000001344"
                            }
                        ],
                        "searchable": "false",
                        "identifier": "BoysPantsSize",
                        "comparable": "true",
                        "name": "Size",
                        "displayable": "true",
                        "uniqueID": "7000000000000000061"
                    }
                ],
                "SKUUniqueID": "12391",
                "Price": [
                    {
                        "SKUPriceDescription": "I",
                        "SKUPriceValue": "45.0",
                        "SKUPriceUsage": "Offer"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "Attributes": [
                    {
                        "usage": "Defining",
                        "Values": [
                            {
                                "values": "Blue",
                                "identifier": "Blue",
                                "uniqueID": "7000000000000001341"
                            }
                        ],
                        "searchable": "false",
                        "identifier": "BoysPantsColor",
                        "comparable": "true",
                        "name": "Color",
                        "displayable": "true",
                        "uniqueID": "7000000000000000060"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "usage": "Defining",
                        "Values": [
                            {
                                "values": "M",
                                "identifier": "M",
                                "uniqueID": "7000000000000001345"
                            }
                        ],
                        "searchable": "false",
                        "identifier": "BoysPantsSize",
                        "comparable": "true",
                        "name": "Size",
                        "displayable": "true",
                        "uniqueID": "7000000000000000061"
                    }
                ],
                "SKUUniqueID": "12392",
                "Price": [
                    {
                        "SKUPriceDescription": "I",
                        "SKUPriceValue": "45.0",
                        "SKUPriceUsage": "Offer"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "Attributes": [
                    {
                        "usage": "Defining",
                        "Values": [
                            {
                                "values": "Blue",
                                "identifier": "Blue",
                                "uniqueID": "7000000000000001341"
                            }
                        ],
                        "searchable": "false",
                        "identifier": "BoysPantsColor",
                        "comparable": "true",
                        "name": "Color",
                        "displayable": "true",
                        "uniqueID": "7000000000000000060"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "usage": "Defining",
                        "Values": [
                            {
                                "values": "L",
                                "identifier": "L",
                                "uniqueID": "7000000000000001346"
                            }
                        ],
                        "searchable": "false",
                        "identifier": "BoysPantsSize",
                        "comparable": "true",
                        "name": "Size",
                        "displayable": "true",
                        "uniqueID": "7000000000000000061"
                    }
                ],
                "SKUUniqueID": "12393",
                "Price": [
                    {
                        "SKUPriceDescription": "I",
                        "SKUPriceValue": "45.0",
                        "SKUPriceUsage": "Offer"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "Attributes": [
                    {
                        "usage": "Defining",
                        "Values": [
                            {
                                "values": "Blue",
                                "identifier": "Blue",
                                "uniqueID": "7000000000000001341"
                            }
                        ],
                        "searchable": "false",
                        "identifier": "BoysPantsColor",
                        "comparable": "true",
                        "name": "Color",
                        "displayable": "true",
                        "uniqueID": "7000000000000000060"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "usage": "Defining",
                        "Values": [
                            {
                                "values": "XL",
                                "identifier": "XL",
                                "uniqueID": "7000000000000001347"
                            }   
                        ],
                        "searchable": "false",
                        "identifier": "BoysPantsSize",
                        "comparable": "true",
                        "name": "Size",
                        "displayable": "true",
                        "uniqueID": "7000000000000000061"
                    }
                ],
                "SKUUniqueID": "12394",
                "Price": [
                    {
                        "SKUPriceDescription": "I",
                        "SKUPriceValue": "45.0",
                        "SKUPriceUsage": "Offer"
                    }
                ]
            }],
            "Attributes": [
                {
                    "usage": "Defining",
                    "Values": [
                        {
                            "values": "S",
                            "extendedValue": [
                                {
                                    "value": "C62",
                                    "key": "UnitOfMeasure"
                                }
                            ],
                            "identifier": "S",
                            "uniqueID": "7000000000000001344"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "values": "M",
                            "extendedValue": [
                                {
                                    "value": "C62",
                                    "key": "UnitOfMeasure"
                                }
                            ],
                            "identifier": "M",
                            "uniqueID": "7000000000000001345"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "values": "L",
                            "extendedValue": [
                                {
                                    "value": "C62",
                                    "key": "UnitOfMeasure"
                                }
                            ],
                            "identifier": "L",
                            "uniqueID": "7000000000000001346"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "values": "XL",
                            "extendedValue": [
                                {
                                    "value": "C62",
                                    "key": "UnitOfMeasure"
                                }
                            ],
                            "identifier": "XL",
                            "uniqueID": "7000000000000001347"
                        }
                    ],
                    "searchable": "false",
                    "dataType": "STRING",
                    "ExtendedValue": [
                        {
                            "extValue": "C62"
                        }
                    ],
                    "identifier": "BoysPantsSize",
                    "comparable": "true",
                    "name": "Size",
                    "description": "Size",
                    "displayable": "true",
                    "uniqueID": "7000000000000000061"
                }, 
                {
                    "usage": "Defining",
                    "Values": [
                        {
                            "values": "Blue",
                            "extendedValue": [{
                                "value": "C62",
                                "key": "UnitOfMeasure"
                            }],
                            "identifier": "Blue",
                            "uniqueID": "7000000000000001341"
                        }
                    ],
                    "searchable": "false",
                    "dataType": "STRING",
                    "ExtendedValue": [
                        {
                            "extValue": "C62"
                        }
                    ],
                    "identifier": "BoysPantsColor",
                    "comparable": "true",
                    "name": "Color",
                    "description": "Color",
                    "displayable": "true",
                    "uniqueID": "7000000000000000060"
                }, 
                {
                    "usage": "Descriptive",
                    "Values": [
                        {
                            "values": "Denim jeans",
                            "identifier": "BCL015_1501",
                            "uniqueID": "7000000000000001368"
                        }
                    ],
                    "searchable": "false",
                    "dataType": "STRING",
                    "ExtendedValue": [
                        {
                            "extValue": "C62"
                        }
                    ],
                    "identifier": "Style",
                    "comparable": "true",
                    "name": "Style",
                    "description": "Style",
                    "displayable": "true",
                    "uniqueID": "7000000000000000010"
                }, 
                {
                    "usage": "Descriptive",
                    "Values": [
                        {
                            "values": "Denim",
                            "identifier": "BCL015_1501",
                            "uniqueID": "7000000000000001358"
                        }
                    ],
                    "searchable": "false",
                    "dataType": "STRING",
                    "ExtendedValue": [
                        {
                            "extValue": "C62"
                        }
                    ],
                    "identifier": "Material",
                    "comparable": "true",
                    "name": "Material",
                    "description": "Material",
                    "displayable": "true",
                    "uniqueID": "7000000000000000009"
                }, 
                {
                    "usage": "Descriptive",
                    "Values": [
                        {
                            "values": "Casual",
                            "identifier": "BCL015_1501",
                            "uniqueID": "7000000000000001378"
                        }
                    ],
                    "searchable": "false",
                    "dataType": "STRING",
                    "ExtendedValue": [
                        {
                            "extValue": "C62"
                        }
                    ],
                    "identifier": "Occasion",
                    "comparable": "true",
                    "name": "Occasion",
                    "description": "Occasion",
                    "displayable": "true",
                    "uniqueID": "7000000000000000011"
                }, 
                {
                    "usage": "Descriptive",
                    "Values": [
                        {
                            "values": "8-16",
                            "identifier": "BCL015_1501",
                            "uniqueID": "7000000000000001348"
                        }
                    ],
                    "searchable": "false",
                    "dataType": "STRING",
                    "ExtendedValue": [
                        {
                            "extValue": "C62"
                        }
                    ],
                    "identifier": "Age",
                    "comparable": "true",
                    "name": "Age",
                    "description": "Age",
                    "displayable": "true",
                    "uniqueID": "7000000000000000053"
                }
            ],
            "subscriptionType": "NONE",
            "metaDescription": "Straight leg denim jeans",
            "title": "Hermitage Straight Leg Denim Jeans | Aurora",
            "disallowRecOrder": "true",
            "hasSingleSKU": "false",
            "partNumber": "BCL015_1501",
            "storeID": "10001",
            "fullImageAltDescription": "Image for Hermitage Straight Leg Denim Jeans from Aurora"
        }
    ],
    "recordSetCount": "1",
    "MetaData": [
        {
            "metaKey": "price",
            "metaData": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```